# Buffered MP4 video won't play

Tags: flash, video, jwplayer, flowplayer

I've integrated flowplayer on my site to play MP4 files but it isn't working as expected.

When click play, every video loads up to 3 MB ( takes about 25 seconds ) before start playing.

When started playing it shows that the video has buffered a lot ( below image, grey portion in timeline) but it still buffers (loading as shown in below image) and even cannot seek within grey portion.

First I thought this is a bug in flowplayer but I also tried jw player, same result. Is this a problem with flash? I've the latest version.

Someone please help me!!

[image]

Comment: Where is this running? Do you have a link?

Comment: This plays for me without issue.

Comment: I did some tests, a file I tested had it's metadata at 3 MB and when I try to play it, the player only starts playing after 3.2 MB of the file loaded ( from Chrome network inspection tool). All the files are the same, only plays after metadata loaded. I've already faststart the files but I do not know what's causing this.

Comment: Perhaps you have a speedy connection so you haven't notice the time taken to load 3 MBs, here in NZ it takes about 20 secs in Chrome.

Comment: update: This is not an issue with my server or the player! I just uploaded a file to mediafire.com and put the direct link to the player and the result is the same. @EthanJWPlayer Is this an encoding issue?

Comment: Here is my video demo http://youtu.be/KQwUEmdRRrQ

Comment: I am using a basic cable connection. How big is the entire file?

Comment: I have no idea what's causing this. All the files are above 100 mb. The file in the demo is 351 mb.

Comment: Well, when a file is large like this, a certain portion needs to be downloaded before it can be played back. Have you had others check this?

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer I ran some tests! You're right, flv files start playing immediately but MP4. Thanks a lot, Appreciate your help. :)

Comment: No problem, any time ;)